# Why elastic does not find my search text?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple instances of one type, each has field displayName. This field is:

```
"Contributor1"
"Contributor2"
...
"Contributor49"
```

I have all mappings/analyzers/etc set to defaults.

I try to find this:

```
fuzzy_like_this_field: { "displayName": { like_text: "49" } }
```

But it does not return any matches. When I try following search texts:

```
"c49" -> nothing
"co49" -> nothing
"con49" -> nothing
"cont49" -> nothing
"contr49" -> nothing
"contri49" -> nothing
"contrib49" -> CORRECT MATCH
```

How I can improve the search? Strange that elastic does not find "49" - it is unique along all sources...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch fuzzy searches on string fields are based on the Levenshtein Edit Distance:

> **String**
>
> When querying string fields, fuzziness is interpreted as a Levenshtein
>   Edit Distance — the number of one character changes that need to be
>   made to one string to make it the same as another string.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness

A detailed explanation of the Levenshtein Edit Distance can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

For purposes of your example, it's the total number of character adds and removals that would be needed to change the term you are searching for to the term you find. The string "contrib49" is much closer to "Contributor49" than "49" is and it falls within the default distance or fuzziness for this field and search.

You can increase the fuzziness with the fuzziness parameter which defaults to .5 : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-flt-field-query.html

Increasing it (let's say .7 or .8) will increase the overall fuzziness it will match.

Overall though are you sure you are using the right approach here? If all you are looking for is wildcard search, a fuzzy search may not be the best way to go - you might want to look at wildcards and ngram analyzers instead.

Comment: Thanks, I am using elastic for the first time and I am not familiar with search methods - fuzzy was a blind shoot :) I will take a look on wildcard/ngram analyzers.

Comment: Hmm, I increased fuzziness to 0.9 (also tried 1.0) and still "49" is not matched. I cant use wildcard - it is general search on website... Maybe I have to store dis field in some different way in index? Display name usually will be short and usually it will contain up to 3 words.

Comment: 1.0 is a very different setting, it has less impact than .9. I'd try .95, or something like 15 (no decimal point it's an integer). In either case if you are trying to match 49 to "Contributor49" it's going to be an expensive query. I'd try looking at ngrams http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Comment: Strange thing: in fact I was able to improve my search DECREASING "fuzinness" param to `0.05` (match for "contr49") while INCREASING "fuziness" to `0.95' gave me worst match rate (match only for "contributor49") - it seems that this param does not mean what I thought? It seems to be "inversed"...